# How to fix undefined method [] for nil:NilClass in OpenUri

Tags: ruby

I'm getting an error sometimes. Here's the basic program:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'
require 'date'
require 'time'

def update_wu
  open("http://api.wunderground.com/api/.......12.json") {|wu|
    json_string = wu.read

    upd_str = ....
      ...
    wu.close
    return upd_str
  }
  return "NULL"
end

loop do
  upd_str = update_wu

  # every 5 minutes 
  t = Time.now
  secs = (t.hour * 60 + t.min) * 60 + t.sec
  wait = ((secs/(5*60)).to_i + 1) * 5 * 60 - secs
  print "#{Time.now.inspect}  #{upd_str} #{wait}\n"

  sleep(wait)
end
```

Here's the error:

```
wu.rb:12:in `block in update_wu': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:155:in `open_uri'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from wu.rb:8:in `update_wu'
```

The program loops every five minutes and then makes the URI call. It will loop dozens of times before it gets the error.

What's up?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Your code won't run because you removed parts of it, inducing syntax errors and making your question off-topic. Don't do that. We need to be able to run the code and reproduce the problem. If we can't reproduce it we can't help you.

Comment: Your "sleep" mechanism is unnecessarily complicated. `Time.now.to_i` returns seconds. `%` performs a modula. `sleep 300 - (Time.now.to_i % 300)` will wake every five minutes.

Comment: "wu.rb:12" means that the problem appears on line 12. You don't show this line.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic code I'd use to look at a site every five minutes and parse a JSON response:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
require 'time'

INTERVAL = 5 * 60

loop do
  data = JSON[open("http://httpbin.org/headers").read]
  puts data

  delay = INTERVAL - (Time.now.to_i % INTERVAL)
  puts "Waiting #{delay} seconds"

  sleep(delay)
end
```

Don't do that though. Hitting a site when you don't need to retrieve a result because it hasn't changed is very bad manners on the internet, and can get you banned.

Instead, you should be checking to see if there is a need to retrieve the data before asking for the whole resource. Typically we do that by sending a HEAD request, and pass the necessary data to the site, which will then tell us if the data has changed, and, if it has, then we issue a GET or POST. See the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for more information.

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.

How to do that is for you to figure it. There are lots of examples out there.

You'll get an exception if the connection can't be made. You'll want to rescue that.